# parse file in C# with Regex and search lines

Tags: c#, regex, search

I have .dat file with many lines, like this :

```
2975,"Koltsovo Airport","Yekaterinburg","Russia","SVX","USSS",56.743099212646,60.802700042725,764,5,"N","Asia/Yekaterinburg","airport","OurAirports"
```

All what i need from this file , is search line by identifier, in this case is USSS, and get 2 values : 56.743099212646, 60.802700042725.

Im write small code, but my level in C# not good to complete my misson :(

```
string re1 = ".*?"; 
string re2 = "(\"USSS\")";  


Regex g = new Regex(re1 + re2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("airports.dat"))
        {                
            string line;
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Match m = g.Match(line);
                if (m.Success)
                {

                    string v = m.Groups[1].Value;
                    MessageBox.Show(v);
                }

            }
        }
```

Please help me, what code need to search line by identifier (example USSS), and get 2 values 56.743099212646, 60.802700042725.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like You should not find USSS, just find Your numbers by `\d+\.\d{12}`

update

version with usss `USSS\",(\d+\.\d{12}),(\d+\.\d{12})` group[1] and [2] contain Your data

Comment: In this file (.dat) have a lot lines, in my program i want search this numbers by identifier (usss). Its possible or i need use something else?

Answer (score 0):

Look for two number after USSS seperated by a ",".

Replace re2 with: "USSS\",([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)"

```
        string re1 = ".*?";
        string re2 = "USSS\",([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+),([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)";

        Regex g = new Regex(re1 + re2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("airports.dat"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Match m = g.Match(line);
                if (m.Success)
                {
                    string v1 = m.Groups[1].Value;
                    string v2 = m.Groups[2].Value;
                    MessageBox.Show(v1);
                    MessageBox.Show(v2);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thnaks for replays! Problem solved by using regex code :

```
\"USSS\",(\d+\.\d{12}),(\d+\.\d{12})
```

and get my values from groups group[1] and [2]

```
Regex g = new Regex(@"\""USSS\"",(\d+\.\d{12}),(\d+\.\d{12})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("airports.dat"))
        {                
            string line;
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Match m = g.Match(line);
                if (m.Success)
                {

                    string v = m.Groups[1].Value;
                    string v2 = m.Groups[2].Value;
                    MessageBox.Show(v);
                    MessageBox.Show(v2);
                }
                // Do stuff with line.
            }
        }
```